# Authenticate users of a pre-existing table

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am thinking to migrate my app from rails to laravel 5, take a look at users migration file:

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at
    end
  end
end
```

So, the question is, how would I change the default used fields names at Laravel 5 to be as the above field names? ex: `password` to `encrypted_password`

I saw some answers for this, but I want the recommended way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5.1 you can set a method in your User model to return the password field...

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->encrypted_password;
}
```

Comment: Is that it? isn't there any thing to override?

Answer (score 0):

In your User model, change following two lines

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'encrypted_password'];

protected $hidden = ['encrypted_password', 'remember_token'];
```

And you want to overwrite the `getAuthPassword()` method in the User model. Then in the `config/auth.php` file

```
'password' => [
    'email' => 'emails.encrypted_password',
    'table' => 'password_resets',
    'expire' => 60,
],
```

For the password reset part, take a look at `vendor/laravel/src/Illuminiate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords`, you need to implement this trait in your app with a few changes.

Comment: Thanks but, how would I override vendor/laravel/src/Illuminiate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords ? and why to set the table "password_resets" in 'password'  at config/auth.php above?

Comment: @SamirSabri you can override any method in the `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController.php`